# PowerShell Script delete AD User that are in a specific Group and a file thats called the same as the login name

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Hello im new to PowerShell and i need some help with a project.

I want to delete all Users that are in the AD Group "to delete" and i also need to delete a file thats called the same as the login name of the deleted user. Every User has one such file stored in the same path.

So i got all the group members into an array with Get-ADGroupMember but i dont quite know how i can filter out just the login name so i can search for the specific file.

I'd very much appreciate it if you could give me some pointers, thank you very much

So i got all the users i need to delete with the cmdlet Get-ADGroupMember "to delete" and stored them in an array. But i dont quite know how i can filter out the login name so i can search for the file i need to delete

Comment: [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps) returns an [`ADPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adprincipal?view=activedirectory-management-10.0). I think you're looking for the `Name` property of this object.

Comment: I managed to get just the samaccountname into my array with `$list_accName = Get-ADGroupMember "to delete" | select-object samaccountname` But now when i want to build a string of the path with `$path="c:\user\test\" + $list_accName[$i]` , the path comes out as `c:\user\test\@{samaccountname=testa}`. What am I missing here to just get the path ending on `testa`?

Comment: That's the wrong property. You want `Name`, not `SamAccountName`. The `SamAccountName` is the qualified name of the user.

Comment: Use `$list_accName = Get-ADGroupMember "to delete" | select-object -ExpandProperty samaccountname` or for short `$list_accName = (Get-ADGroupMember "to delete").samaccountname`.  That way you recieve an array with just the SamAccountNames as string, not as objects. (@Jesse The `Name` proerty is definitely **not** what you want here)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to list put all account names that belong to the group "to delete" into an array and concatenate these names with your path:

```
$myarray = (Get-ADGroupMember "to delete").SamAccountName

foreach ($account in $myarray) {
    "C:\user\test\" + $account
}
```

You can update the foreach statement to include [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3) if you want to remove files with these paths. First, use the `-WhatIf` parameter to run the command in "dry run" mode (it does not actually delete any files, but shows what would happen if the cmdlet runs).